# How to write a function for updating audit column in oracle

Tags: oracle, function, triggers

I'm trying to write a trigger to update couple of columns in a table for that I wrote a function which is doing actual functionality and trigger to execute that function:

But I'm getting the exception can someone guide me what went wrong here:

Function I'm writing :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION myFunction() 
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
     IF OLD.timestamp IS NOT DISTINCT FROM NEW.timestamp THEN
    NEW.lst_updt_ts = now();
     END IF;    
    RETURN NEW;
END;

Trigger:

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER Mytrigger 
BEFORE UPDATE ON mytable
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  myFunction;
END;
```

When I'm compiling the function

below is the error I'm getting :

PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ")" when expecting one of the following:

current delete exists prior

Compile error at line 1, column 34

Answer (score 1):

The syntax is definitely not an Oracle. As far as I can understand, you need to update lst_updt_ts to current timestamp if user tries to update it manually. I'd try to write something like that

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER Mytrigger 
BEFORE UPDATE ON mytable
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF :OLD.timestamp <> :NEW.timestamp THEN
    :NEW.lst_updt_ts = sysdate; -- or systimestamp;
  END IF;    
END;
```

Comment: this is working for me thanks, a small correction : is missed while updating time stamp , :NEW.lst_updt_ts = sysdate; . I just added ":" Thanks a ton :)

Answer (score 1):

The DBMS complains about you using an open parentheses here: `myFunction(` and then not having any parameters before closing with `)`. Remove the parentheses.

But then, Oracle doesn't support this trigger function syntax known from PostgreSQL. Neither does it support `IS NOT DISTINCT FROM` yet.

Unfortunately, you cannot even pass the row like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION myFunction(p_new IN OUT mytable.ROWTYPE%)
```

because Oracle doesn't treat :new and :old as row records. I've suggested this in Oracle Database Ideas last year. You can vote for it :-) Link: https://community.oracle.com/tech/apps-infra/discussion/comment/16785577#Comment_16785577

There are two ways that I see for now:

1. Put the code in your trigger directly.
2. Write a function getting :OLD.timestamp and :NEW.timestamp and :NEW.lst_updt_ts and returning the altered :NEW.lst_updt_ts.